# Enviar dados para o cliente sem usar um url adicional

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express.js

Olá. O que desejo saber é a melhor forma de enviar dados pro cliente sendo que este dados serão recebidos por meio de uma função (que pode ser executada em um click).

No exemplo abaixo irei renderizar uma página (estou usando o express no node.js):

```
app.get('/exemplo', function (req, res) {
  res.render('exemplo.html');
});
```

Mas caso eu queira enviar dados a página renderizada, serei obrigado a usar **uma *url* adicional**? Como abaixo:

```
app.get('/exemplo', function (req, res) {
  res.render('exemplo.html');
});
var data = {...}
app.get('/exemplo/data', function (req, res) {
  res.send(data);
});
```

Ou poderia fazer os dois usando a mesma *url*? Ou existiria alguma outra forma de enviar dados, por exemplo, dados do usuário para a página, usando o ***expressJs***.

Obs.: Não utilizo o pré-processador Jade.

Desde já, grato.

Comment: Não dá simplesmente pra mandar um <script type...>var meuJson = { ... }<script> junto do HTML? Provavelmente tem mil maneiras simples de resolver o problema, mas acho que a pergunta está um pouco vaga. De qualquer forma, uma coisa é fato: qq URL que você disponibilize pro JS do cliente, o cliente pode usar como quiser para obter os dados que o JS obteria. Outra solução seria concatenar o JSON depois do HTML e dividir em 2 strings separadas depois. Só dá pra responder com mais detalhes.

Comment: @Bacco, olhe a minha edição. Veja se ficou mais claro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar a mesma rota no Express e enviares os dados numa *query string*, como um GET.

Podes fazer isso com ajax e depois no Express usar o [`.query`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query), primeiro argumento (`req`) no controlador.

Um exemplo seria assim:

No JavaScript, [usando ajax](https://jsfiddle.net/r3g9nm09/):

```
var data = {foo: 'bar'};
ajax(data, function(res) {
    console.log('Resposta do servidor:', res);
});
```

E no Node/Express, usando [o `req.query`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query):

```
app.get('/exemplo', function (req, res) {
  var txt = req.query.foo + ' bar';
  res.render({resposta: txt}); // vai mandar de volta a string para o JS
});
```

Comment: Sergio, como ficaria o uso da queryString em um objeto vindo do servidor e sendo lido no js?

Comment: @SamirBraga como assim vindo do servidor? Queres dizer enviando dados do servidor de volta para o ajax?

Comment: Isso. No seu exemplo, você enviou o objeto do ajax para o servidor e o leu com o `req.query`. Onde posso ler, no js, essa `{resposta: text}`?

Comment: @SamirBraga viste o link que coloquei em "No JavaScript, usando ajax:"? isso vai para um jsFiddle com um ajax com JS nativo. Se usares esse está lá o exemplo, vai ser o `res` da callback. Como escrevi aqui na resposta: `console.log('Resposta do servidor:', res);`. Se usares jQuery é o mesmo, vai ser passado à callback. Consegui explicar-me?

Comment: Sergio, é eu tinha visto o JsFiddle, só estava com problemas pra usar o `prepareData()` junto com o `Angular`, e estou com pouco tempo pra testar agora, mas imagino que eu tenha entendido bem. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: @SamirBraga ah, pois no angular o ajax dele já deve ter isso integrado. O meu exemplo foi com JS nativo. Mas esse prepareData é só para quando se envia, para receber só é usada a linha `callback(JSON.parse(request.responseText));`, imagino que o angular tenha também uma maneira de responder com um JSON.